# How do I split and embolden this string with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this string  and I used string.bold() method to make bold the string. While debugging this JavaScript I found that this string is appended with bold tag, with the HTML tag `<B>6,00,234</B>`. Now I need to show this bold result in one area and I need to show the same result without this bold option in another area.

Using JavaScript how can I achieve this?

**string result = 6,00,234**

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the quotes?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? You ask about string splitting in the subject but your question itself seems to only involve concatenating two strings.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code backing your question so we can figure out what you want?

Comment: You need to learn how to format your questions, so people can actually see what you are asking - code needs to be code highlighted or the html tags will disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
var str = "<B>6,00,234</B>";

var result = str.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,''); // 6,00,234
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using JavaScript's [`split`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#split) method?

```
var str = "6,00,234";
var arr = new Array();
arr = str.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're saying how would you extract the content between the  tag? If so, regular expressions groups are useful for that. For example:

```
 var aString = '<B>6,00,234</B>'; //the original string
 var regex = /(<B>)([\w,\d]+)(<\/B>)/g; //regular expression
 var match = regex.exec(aString); //get the match for that string
 console.log(match[2]); //should give you your number
```

This works because when you execute your regular expression, you will get the match but split into three, which is why you indicated three parenthesis blocks.